# Как изменить значение Scale дисплея на Ubuntu 18.04.3

Tags: linux, ubuntu, настройки

Интерфейс на ноутбуке в Ubuntu 18.04.3 очень маленький, практически неразличимый. Если оставить значение в настройках дисплея Scale = 100%, то можно ослепнуть, если ставить 200% - интерфейс становится слишком большим. Хотелось бы поставить значение вроде 120%, но как это сделать - неизвестно. На Ubuntu 19.04 это проблема лечится командой: gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']" , но на 18.04.3 она не производит никакого эффекта. Что делать?
Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: `google://xrandr+scale`